# showing values having counts of another value

Tags: r, counting

I am looking for outliers in data; which places are the worst?

```
    place = rep(c('AL','AK','AZ','AR','CA','CO','CT','DE','FL','GA','HI'), times=4)
    measure = rep(c('meas1','meas2','meas3','meas4'), each=11)
    set.seed(200)
    rating = sample(c('good','bad'), size = 44, prob=c(2,1), replace=T)
    df = data.frame(place, measure, rating)
```

This takes multiple steps now; first finding the places with any bad ratings and putting that result into a table, to tell me CA is the worst, with 3 "bads":

```
bads = df %>% 
 filter(rating == 'bad')

sort(table(bads$place), decreasing = T)
> bads
   place measure rating
1     AR   meas1    bad
2     CA   meas1    bad
3     CO   meas1    bad
4     CT   meas1    bad
5     DE   meas2    bad
6     AK   meas3    bad
7     CA   meas3    bad
8     AK   meas4    bad
9     CA   meas4    bad
10    FL   meas4    bad
11    GA   meas4    bad

> sort(table(bads$place), decreasing = T)

CA AK AR CO CT DE FL GA AL AZ HI 
 3  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0
```

[Please disregard the folowing...]
*Also, if the rating were numerical instead of categorical, is there an analogous way to get the places which fall into the highest/lowest quartile (not sure if that would be a separate question)?*

If another post answers this, please point to it; I have looked at quite a few posts about counting and aggregation so far.

Comment: Please use `set.seed` to make your example reproducible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data.table package is pretty handy for this kind of thing:

```
> data.table(df)[rating=='bad', .N,by="place"][order(-N)]
   place N
1:    CA 3
2:    AK 2
3:    AR 1
4:    CO 1
5:    CT 1
6:    DE 1
7:    FL 1
8:    GA 1
```

Comment: yes. I am more familiar with SQL, and I think that the sqldf version of that is the most general  -- i.e.  sqldf("SELECT  place, rating, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM df GROUP BY place, rating ORDER BY rating, count DESC").     If nobody offers a tidyverse or base R approach, I will mark your answer as the solution

Answer (score 1):

As for the main question, maybe you can do without `sort`, since it's generally time consuming.

```
tb <- table(bads$place)
tb[which.max(tb)]
```

As for the second question, I'm not sure what you mean by *places which fall into the highest/lowest quartile* but maybe you can get some inspiration with the following.

```
rating2 <- sample(5, 44, TRUE)
df2 <- data.frame(place, measure, rating2)

qq <- quantile(df2$rating2)
y <- findInterval(df2$rating2, qq)
names(y) <- df2$place
```

Comment: thanks for the which.max. I'd like to see the top few outliers, not just the very max.

Comment: The findInterval  results did not include the name of a place.

Comment: I was thinking that aggregate or group by or tally or count() would somehow work here, but I could not figure out how to do that.

Comment: @cumin If you want the top few outliers then you'll need `sort` as in you original code. As for the names in `findInterval`, I've just edited my code.

Comment: I see now that numerical measures can't be summed or aggregated the way the measure="bad" can be summed. In the example there are four separate measures, and for each one I would find which places had the worst ratings. In other words, it really would be a separate question.

Comment: @cumin Are you looking for something like `with(df, aggregate(measure, list(measure, rating), FUN = length))`?

Comment: maybe; I don't fully understand the call to "list()" within aggregate().

Comment: I will ask a new question about how to do this in a tidyverse way, which I realize is what I really wanted to know.